# Issue changing IE IP using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, proxy, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I have been using this code for some time now to successfully assign a proxy to IE  then I used `WebBrowser` control to navigate to pages (can not be any other way `HttpWebRequest` etc cause of some reasons).

The code is :

```
private void ChangeProxySetting(String proxyHost, Boolean proxyEnabled)
{
    const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
    const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;

    Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO struct_IPI;
    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxyHost);
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

    IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);
    bool iReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
}
```

But suddenly the code has stopped working; it bypasses that no error still returns TRUE but I don't see any proxy in IE.

Before as soon as it passed this line the IE had a proxy in it !

Any suggestions ? Or than the registry way?

Comment: IE Version it used to work and IE Version it is not working

Comment: Same Version it used to work and same work it does not anymore.(latest one)